# Why is this URI valid by RCF 2396 standards?

Tags: java, uri

I was playing around with non stringy types for an application loader i've been developing. As a typo, I forgot to include the protocol part of a specific URI. I expected the java test to fail due to an invalid URI... however this statement seems to work...

```
URI uri = URI.create("contacts.addresses.genericAddress")
```

To me, theres no standard for using a dot as a scheme part... and I thought the scheme part was always required?

Does anyone know why?

Comment: If the Java code accepts the URI that does not necessarily mean the URI is valid according to RFC 2396.

Comment: Ditto.  There's a list of things that Java assumes are implied by the spec, but not actually part of the spec, so Java is a bit more permissive that what the spec allows.  That said, your string looks like a valid host name to me.

Comment: Ah, here: "specified by the grammar in RFC 2396, Appendix A" and appendix A allows a URI to be a *relative path*, with no host name or scheme.  So "this.and.that" might just be a file name like "this.html" (dot's are valid as a file element name -- i.e., pchars in a path segment).

Comment: @SimeonVisser its important to note, that the method was used because it stated it forced proper convention... I just did not read the spec well enough to know why it was valid. But the java code does conform to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add my comment as an answer because I think it's correct:

From the Java URI documentation: "specified by the grammar in RFC 2396, Appendix A" and appendix A allows a URI to be a *relative path,* with no host name or scheme. So "this.and.that" might just be a file name like "this.html" (dot's are valid as a file element name -- i.e., pchars in a path segment).

Comment: That makes quite a bit of sense. I read through that document way before I posted that question. I musta missed this. Thank you very much.